# How to do a for loop of filenames with spaces using find

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have the following script - its supposed to loop files names using find but it seams to break the files names up by a space? I need the file names to remain intact

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find -name "*.avi"`
do
./myscript $file
done
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux command to remove directories with white spaces](http://serverfault.com/questions/385474/linux-command-to-remove-directories-with-white-spaces)

Comment: I updated the question to be more accurate of what I want to do

Comment: See [BashFAQ #020: How can I find and deal with file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find -name "*.avi" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 echo
```

You don't have to `echo` in `xargs`:

```
find -name "*.avi" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ./myscript
```

Comment: This is another way to output the filename - I need to loop file names to another script (in the example above I replaced the command with echo)

Comment: So show us what you actually want to do then.  We can't help you do what you want to do if you don't tell us what you want to do.

Answer (score 13):

Also: `find -name "*.avi" -exec ./myscript '{}' \;`

Womble's answer definitely works in the majority of cases, but Xargs isn't perfect with spaces across all implementations. I've never found find's 'exec' mode to break. Solaris was particularly cranky in that respect.

Obviously, the '-print' would be better for simply generating output for a list of files in a for loop. But if you're running a command on a list of files, it's more efficient to just run the '-exec' option.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need recursion:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.avi
do
    ./myscript "$file"
done
```

Note that the quotes around the variable are essential.

**Edit:**

As kojiro points out, if you need recursion and you have Bash 4, you can add `shopt -s globstar` and change the glob to `**/*.avi`.

Comment: If a file name has spaces, this method will break. If it has \n or other strange characters, it is also a security risk. Think of "/tmp/file\n/etc/shadow"

Comment: @hayalci: No, you are *completely* wrong. It works perfectly with such filenames and without any security risks. Globbing with a `for` loop is the *correct* way to do this when recursion is not needed.

Comment: If he does need recursion and has bash 4, he can just use `shopt -s globstar; for file in **/*.avi`

Comment: @kojiro: Thanks, I should have mentioned that and I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: You are right, I confused the issue with "for i in \`ls *.avi\`" case

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solutions based on xargs and the find -exec there is also the option of piping to while read. It has the benefit of allowing you to structure your script in a more classic loop manner. Let me apply it to your example.

```
find -name "*.avi" | while read avifile; do
  ./myscript "$avifile"
done
```

Comment: By default `read` will support escaping, so you need `-r`. And your solution will break with filenames containing newlines.

Comment: @Pierre: I have so far never encounted a regular space situation where I have needed the -r parameter (to read?), but thanks for the pointer, I'll look into it. Agree that this solution would break on newline. Assumed the original questioner only dealt with the regular space character. When expecting arbitrary whitespace, or any other really crazy characters I agree on xargs -0 being the better choice. Well, either that or doing something more robust in a language such as Perl, Python, etc.

Comment: `-r` is not needed for spaces, but in case a backslash appears in the filename.